# mysqldump only adding insert statements for first row of MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, database-backups

I want to do a FULL database backup with ALL the data in it as insert statements. I am using this command so far:

```
mysqldump -u root myDatabase -p > full_backup.sql
```

From what I've read, this should dump all the data and database structures into my full_backup file. However, it only seams to get the first row of that db in my case. Here is an excerpt from the dump file:

```
LOCK TABLES `admin_users` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `admin_users` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `admin_users` VALUES (1,'it@konditormeister.com','PASSWORDHASH',NULL,NULL,NULL,34,'2016-06-30 20:43:01','2016-06-21 16:41:25','MY_IP_ADDRESS','192.168.$
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `admin_users` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

There are about 12 admin users in actuality, and I can pull all of them up using the mysql command line, however, this is the only insert statement I get. This is similar on all other tables I have.

So my question is: How do I get mysqldump to dump ALL of the rows in my database/tables so that I could potentially completely recreate the database from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

it seams that adding the -e option fixes this problem and adds the rest of the rows.